# http.request returning var for use in Javascript in Node

Tags: node.js

I've been trying to connect node to a web page and return the result in the same program. Here's the code I have:

```
var http = require('http'),
    sys = require('sys'),
    fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  host: 'myurl.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/path/to/file',
  method: 'POST'
};

var myglobal = "the test";

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    myglobal = chunk;
    console.log("myglobal = " + myglobal);
  });
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();

console.log("outside of http request: myglobal = " + myglobal);
```

Now what I want to happen is for "myglobal" to have the contents of the output of the web page "myurl.com" at the end of the program. This doesn't happen however and I can't seem to figure out how to get the contents from the "chunk" into another variable in the program. I thought the contents would be in either the "req" or "res" variable but I dumped the vars and couldn't find the output in either place. So at the end, "myglobal" still says "the test", where the "myglobal" within the http.request code has the output of "chunk". Just curious to know what it is I'm missing here. Thanks.

Darryl

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get you right. You want to work with the data (the body) you get via the POST request right? Then you have to continue working after all chunks have been received:

```
var http = require('http'),
    sys = require('sys'),
    fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  host: 'blog.depold.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/post/5936116582/changes-in-sequelize-1-0-0',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  var data = ""
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) { data += chunk })
  res.on('end', function() {
    console.log("finished request", "data length:", data.length)
    console.log("go on working here")
  })
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end()
```

Comment: Yes, it works if I print out from the "go on working here" area within the http.request area. The problem I have is I then want to send the output of the page via a socket, and I can't seem to get sockets working correctly from inside of the http.request area. My socket connection works fine outside of that last http.request bracket, which is why I'd like to access the POST output outside of there. I can list a better explanation if I haven't made this clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Been banging my head with this one for the past couple weeks and after trying a bunch of stuff decided to add "\0" at the end and it worked! So it seems that the socket.write automatically appends the "\0" outside of the "http.request" block, but doesn't append it within that block. So it would "queue" any http.request messages until I sent a message outside of that block, which would automatically be terminated by "\0". Why it works that way I have no idea, but there it is.